# Delete Document and all references in another Schema MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a schema for `Forms` and another one for `Documents`...

Each `Document` must have a reference `_id` of the `Form` that is related to,
  so in database I can have many `Documents` with the same `Form._id`.

I want to know how to create a `DELETE` function for the `Forms` to do the following:

- Find all `Documents` that have this `Form._id` and `DELETE` it all and then 
  delete the `Form` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so lets start of with some basic forms and documents in our database

```
db.forms.insertMany([
   { _id : 1, name : "Form 1"},
   { _id : 2, name : "Form 2"}
]);

db.documents.insertMany([
  { _id : 1, formId : 1, name : "Doc 1" },
  { _id : 2, formId : 1, name : "Doc 2" },
  { _id : 3, formId : 1, name : "Doc 3" },
  { _id : 4, formId : 2, name : "Doc 4" }
])

> db.forms.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Form 1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Form 2" }

> db.documents.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "formId" : 1, "name" : "Doc 1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "formId" : 1, "name" : "Doc 2" }
{ "_id" : 3, "formId" : 1, "name" : "Doc 3" }
{ "_id" : 4, "formId" : 2, "name" : "Doc 4" }
```

Then we can create a simple function to pass in the form id and find and delete all the documents for that form id.

```
function removeForm(formId){

   var ids = db.documents.find({ formId : formId}, { _id : 1 } ).map(function(doc){ return doc["_id"]; });

   db.documents.remove( { "_id" : { "$in" : ids } } );

   db.forms.remove( { "_id" : formId } );
}
```

Then we can call removeForm.

```
removeForm(1);
```

Then we'll see our documents and forms deleted

```
> db.forms.find()
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Form 2" }
> db.documents.find()
{ "_id" : 4, "formId" : 2, "name" : "Doc 4" }
```

Answer (score 0):

In our application we do it like that:
When a user got deleted, delete also its corrosponding Scans & Categories

```
const scanModel = require("./Scan");
const categoryModel = require("./Category");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
})

userSchema.pre("remove", function(next) {
  // 'this' is the user being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
  // to be notified of the calls' result.
  scanModel.remove({ user: this._id }).exec();
  categoryModel.remove({ user: this._id }).exec();
  next();
});
```

Comment: When I use it I get this error: formSchema.pre is not a function